# MYSQL Returning result without empty fields

Tags: mysql

The following code below gives me a result of

[image]

but how do I make it so that I get a result of

[image]

**Code:**

```
SELECT * FROM `shop_shipping_rules` LEFT JOIN `countries` ON `shop_shipping_rules`.shop_shipping_rule_country_iso = `countries`.iso 
LEFT JOIN `shop_shipping_regions` ON `shop_shipping_regions`.shop_shipping_rule_region_code = `shop_shipping_rules`.shop_shipping_rule_region_code
WHERE `website_id` = 64 AND `shop_shipping_rule_name` IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

In your predicate, filter out empty fields.

```
AND `shop_shipping_rule_name` IS NOT NULL AND `shop_shipping_rule_name` <> ''
```

It's also best practice to stay away from `SELECT *` and use a column list. Also, you should use aliases and be explicit with your columns.

You will probably want to go through these and make the empty values `NULL`:

```
UPDATE `shop_shipping_rules` 
SET `shop_shipping_rule_name` = NULL 
WHERE `shop_shipping_rule_name` = ''
```

Comment: `OR` should be `AND`.